# How to write, read and delete a file in a single script in C programming

Tags: c

I created a file and filled it with some entries. However, I want to read this file and show it on the screen. Also, after showing the entries, I want it to be deleted with my permission. But I am stuck at this point please help me.

**EDIT:** Code is updated but still couldn't figure it out how to do :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char name[20], surname[20], city[30], country[30], gender[15]; 
int count = 0;   

int main() {
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("C:\\FurkanArslan.txt", "r+");
    
    while (count < 10) { // every step provides 5 new data, so 5*10 will provide 50 data in total.
        printf("\n*Please enter required information: \n");   
        
        printf("Name   :"); scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Surname:"); scanf("%s", surname);
        printf("Country:"); scanf("%s", country); 
        printf("City   :"); scanf("%s", city);
        printf("Gender :"); scanf("%s", gender);

        fprintf(f1, " %s | %s | %s | %s | %s\n\n", name, surname, gender, city, country);
        count++;    
    }
    
    fclose(f1); 
    
    printf("\n<<<<<%d data has been successfully saved!>>>> \n", count * 5);    
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    
    f1 = fopen("C:\\FurkanArslan.txt", "r");
    
    char c, answer; 
    while ((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);   // In this part I displayed file on the screen. 
    
    printf("\n\n <<<< %d entries are displayed on the screen! >>>>", count * 5);
        
    printf("\n\nWould you like to remove your file [Y/N] ?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    
    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') {
        remove("f1");
        printf("\n\n***File successfully removed!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the file? Are you looking for [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove)?

Comment: Yes, that will be useful for my next step thanks but can you help me on displaying on screen? I want to display file content on the screen first then I'll add deleting part.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the content of a file you have to open it and read it letter by letter, after that, you can use the `putchar` function to output the current character

```
FILE *fp = fopen("path/to/file.txt","r");

char c;
while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    putchar(c);

fclose(fp);
```

after that to remove a file you need to use the `remove` function, which receives the name of the file as paramter.

```
remove("my_file.txt");
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply I did applied the information you gave but still having problems. I'll upgrade my code could you please check it and tell my mistakes. It doesn't display on the screen and also doesn't delete at the moment.

Comment: The remove function receive the name of the file you want to delete. In this case: remove("C:\\FurkanArslan.txt");

Comment: `c` must have type `int` for proper detection of `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- there is no need to make the variables and arrays global, just define them in the body of the `main()` function.
- you should tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store in the destination array with a length specifier in the format string (eg: `"%19s"`) and check for conversion success.
- the variable `c` used in the reading loop must have type `int` for proper detection of `EOF`. `fgetc()` returns a positive byte value if successful and the special negative value `EOF` at end of file.
- you do not need to reopen the file after writing to it. Sine you opened it for update mode, you can just seek back to the beginning of the file with `rewind(f1)` or `fseek(f1, 0L, SEEK_SET)`.
- the file is open for *read and update* mode ("r+"): it will fail if the file does not exist. You should open it in *write and update* mode with `"w+"` to create or truncate it.
- you should check that `fopen` succeeds at opening the file, otherwise you invoke undefined behavior passing a null stream pointer to `fprintf`.
- to remove the file, `remove()` takes the filename as its argument. You must close the file before attempting to remove it.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *filename = "C:\\FurkanArslan.txt";
    char name[20], surname[20], city[30], country[30], gender[15]; 
    int count = 0;   

    FILE *f1 = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    while (count < 10) { // every step provides 5 new data, so 5*10 will provide 50 data in total.
        printf("\n*Please enter required information: \n");   

        printf("Name   :"); if (scanf("%19s", name) != 1) break;
        printf("Surname:"); if (scanf("%19s", surname) != 1) break;
        printf("Country:"); if (scanf("%29s", country) != 1) break; 
        printf("City   :"); if (scanf("%29s", city) != 1) break;
        printf("Gender :"); if (scanf("%14s", gender) != 1) break;

        fprintf(f1, " %s | %s | %s | %s | %s\n\n", name, surname, gender, city, country);
        count++;    
    }

    printf("\n<<<<< %d data has been successfully saved to %s! >>>>\n",
           count * 5, filename);
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");

    rewind(f1); 

    int c; 
    while ((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);

    printf("\n\n <<<< %d entries are displayed on the screen! >>>>\n", count);
    fclose(f1);

    printf("\nWould you like to remove your file [Y/N] ?");
    char answer;
    if (scanf(" %c", &answer) == 1 && (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')) {
        if (remove(filename)) {
            printf("\n\n***Error removing file %s: %s\n",
                   filename, strerror(errno));
        } else {
            printf("\n\n***File %s successfully removed!\n", filename);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```